# jQuery .data() to store id for later access? or other method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I am trying to append a div to the body, so

```
$('<div>').appendTo(document.body);
```

However instead of giving that div an ID attribute association so I can access it later, I would like to use jQuery.data() to access that div later so actions can be applied to it.

```
$('<div>').data('#myid').appendTo(document.body);
```

now how do I access it later.

Comment: you cant. you lose the pointer to it. Store it as a varaible.

Comment: well I don't want to associate an ID with the DIV it's tacky.  Any othe methods?

Comment: I would not recommend using `data()`. It has about as much of a use-case as using `goto` (it *does* exist in some contexts, but is generally "not a good way"). Alternatives include: closures (variables), object properties, discrete manual lookup-tables, "using id or something else selectable", etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var later = $('<div>').appendTo(document.body);
// ...
later.actions();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is sounds pretty wierd. Even if you set some kind of `id` over the data- expando, you wouldn't know where to access it later. You don't have a reference to the element which contains that data property.

Best way to keep a reference for a newly created node is, to store it in a local variable.

```
var $newdiv = $('<div>').appendTo(document.body);
```

**Referrencing to your comment**

Almost all jQuery methods return the wrapped set containing jQuery objects. These objects in turn, hold a reference to the DOM node. You can think of it like a bridge. On the one side is your `ECMAland` (Javascript) and on the other side, its `DOMland`. If you cross that bridge to get a reference from a DOM node (which is expensive btw), you can (and should!) store that reference in `ECMAland`. The next time you want to access the `DOM node`, you don't need to cross the bridge and pay the expensive toll, you still have that references and can manipulate the DOM node.

Comment: this is great, so lets say I append the div with newdiv.appendTo(document.body).hide().  How can I keep from appending it over and over again. I tried doing if (newdiv.length != 0) {} <- this is returning 1 even if I haven't appended the div to the dom yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you must get it later without id simply iterate over every object in the DOM and check whether it's your div.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("*").length; i++) {
    if ($(document.getElementsByTagName("*")[i]).data("isMyDiv")) {
         var myDiv = $(document.getElementByTagName("*")[i]);
    } 
}

if (myDiv !== undefined) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Alternatively you can write efficient code.